# Switching places in Bootstrap navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

as you can see in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lakshkhamesra/nvc703yw/) I have created a responsive navigation menu using Bootstrap. However, I want to know how do I get the social icons to appear on the right side on small devices and the navigation button on the left side. I am sorry I am new to this and I Googled it but can't find a solution.

You can see an example of what I am trying to achieve [here](http://venice.thevenusdesign.com/) (the top black navigation menu.)

Here is the HTML code:-

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse5" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-tumblr" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-soundcloud" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-vimeo-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-rss" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div id="navbarCollapse5" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Text Here...">
                <button><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </form>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use CSS flex property `flex-direction: row-reverse` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) is the document for flex

Answer (score 0):

You can use css media queries for this.
Something like this,

```
@media (min-width: 500px) {
   .cls1 {
     float: left;
   }
}

@media (min-width: 501px) {
   .cls2 {
      float: right;
   }
}
```

I've updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nvc703yw/1/).